# Dismiss ModalViewController from subview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, modalviewcontroller, subview

I have a problem with the function call:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In MainViewController, I can launch a image picker and dismiss as usual by clicking the cancel button.

```
(IBAction) LaunchInMain:(id)sender{

    MainAppDelegate *app = (MainAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //elcPicker is a customized image picker
    [app.viewController presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
    [elcPicker release];
    [albumController release];

- (void)elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now, instead of launching it direct it in Main, I add a subview first and launch the image picker from the subview using the same launch method.

**Problem:**

The image picker cannot be dismissed and the subview cannot be shown again. So  the  screen will remain at the image picker no matter what I click.

I have been trying with some other calls like without any success:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I am happy with any help or idea. If you think more information should be provided, I can add more codes.

Comment: are u sure self is your elcPicker? just try [elcPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be try

`[app.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, my workaround is very similar to what you propose. Basically, I just the same controller to dismiss it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you:

```
[self.view dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if you are presenting a modal view from a UISplitViewController.  It can also be applied in so many other ways...

First, create an instance in your .h file for your appDelegate, (`AppDelegate_iPad *appDelegate`) then put this in your viewDidLoad or comparable method:

```
ipadDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPad *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Now, present the first modal view like this:

```
    YOURVC *vc = [[YOURVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"YOURVC" bundle:nil];
    [ipadDelegate.splitViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
```

Say you have a subview, like a UITableView, and want to dismiss the modal from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  All you have to do to dismiss your modal with a subview is create another ipadDelegate instance inside your subview's .h (if needed), reference the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] again, and dismiss:

```
[ipadAppDelegate.splitViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Essentially, as long-winded as it may be, use your appDelegate's controller to present and dismiss the the modal if you need to maintain a persistent reference to the presentingViewController...because all the things above just don't work in my case.

If you're presenting with your ipadDelegate, make sure you check the mode of presentation in your MainWindow_iPad.xib.  Your "Transition Style" should be "Cover Vertical" and "Presentation" should be "Current Context" or your modal may present behind other views.